# Datatables - Refresh/Reload ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Hi folks I was able to sucessfully create a datatable that would get it's data from an ajax call. So for the initial loading is working fine. I created a button called refresh and I was hoping that if I call my function  `initiatearchiveIncidents` it would go and fetch my data again and reload the table but instead im getting the error `cannot re-initialise the Datatable`.

So I tried doing `dtTable.ajax.reload();` but this fails because it dosent understand my ajax call. Would anyone know how to do this properly?

```
    initiatearchiveIncidents: function () {

        $.getJSON(this.basePath() + '/XPROD_Incidents?$filter=ÉtatValue%20eq%20%27Fermé%27&$orderby=Modifié asc',
            function (data) {
            //Sharepoint REST returns a nested data format, so we go deep to get the useful parts
              var myData = data.d.results;
              moment.locale('fr');

            //this is the key part of datatables       
                dtTable = $('#example').DataTable({

                    data: myData,
                    columns:[
                        {
                                "width": "30px",
                                sortable: false,
                                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                return "<button class='edit_button btn btn-default btn-sm' name ='btnSubmit' type='button' value='Edit' data-ID='"+full.ID+"'><i class='fa fa-pencil fa-2'></i></button>";
                                }
                        },
                        { data: "Incident", "width": "75px" },        
                        {
                                "width": "65px",
                                sortable: false,
                                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                return "<h4><span class='priorité_span'>"+full.PrioritéValue+ "</span></h4>";
                                }
                        },      
                        { data: "Composante","width": "75px",className: "over_flow_control" },         
                        { data: "Description","width": "300px",className: "over_flow_control" },
                        { data: "Début_imputabilité","width": "100px"  },
                        { data: "ResponsableValue","width": "100px",className: "over_flow_control"  }

                        ],
                        "order": [[ 5, "desc" ]],
                    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
                    IncidentManager.table_conditional_format();
                    $('#loading').hide("slow");
                    },

                })
            });

    },
```

Comment: you ve to destroy the table first `dtTable.destroy();`

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the default Ajax functionality of Datatables? (https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html)

Comment: Tried the dtTable.destroy(): but it removes my table al together and when I try to append to my tbody it dosent work anymore. I may need to rethink my approch with the destroy() method.

Comment: I tried the regular ajax function but for some reason it dosen't seem to like it when I put `data: data.d.results` I get errors stating data is null. I found it easier just using getJson.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your `initiatearchiveIncidents()` function to use jQuery DataTables Ajax functionality with `ajax.url` and `ajax.dataSrc` options, see below.

When you need to reload the data, just call `$('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload()`, see [`ajax.reload()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29) for more details.

```
initiatearchiveIncidents: function() {

    moment.locale('fr');

    //this is the key part of datatables       
    dtTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: this.basePath() + '/GDI_PROD_Incidents?$filter=ÉtatValue%20eq%20%27Fermé%27&$orderby=Modifié asc',
            dataSrc: "d.results"
        },
        columns: [
            {
                "width": "30px",
                sortable: false,
                "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                    return "<button class='edit_button btn btn-default btn-sm' name ='btnSubmit' type='button' value='Edit' data-ID='" + full.ID + "'><i class='fa fa-pencil fa-2'></i></button>";
                }
            }, {
                data: "Incident",
                "width": "75px"
            }, {
                "width": "65px",
                sortable: false,
                "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                    return "<h4><span class='priorité_span'>" + full.PrioritéValue + "</span></h4>";
                }
            }, {
                data: "Composante",
                "width": "75px",
                className: "over_flow_control"
            }, {
                data: "Description",
                "width": "300px",
                className: "over_flow_control"
            }, {
                data: "Début_imputabilité",
                "width": "100px"
            }, {
                data: "ResponsableValue",
                "width": "100px",
                className: "over_flow_control"
            }

        ],
        "order": [[5, "desc"]],
        "drawCallback": function(settings) {
            IncidentManager.table_conditional_format();
            $('#loading').hide("slow");
        }

    });
},
```